# How to create a function with three arguments

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that takes three arguments for my homework and have tried it several times but no luck! Much appreciated for some advice or help :)

I have already created the following:

```
##### 1)
> raceIDs
[1] "GER" "SUI" "NZ2" "US1" "US2" "POR" "FRA" "AUS" "NZ1" "SWE"

##### 2)
#For each "raceIDs", there is a csv file which I have made a loop to read and created a list of data frames (assigned to the symbol "boatList")
#For example, if I select "NZ1" the output is:
> head(boatList[[9]]) #Only selected the first six lines as there is more than 30000 rows
  Boat       Date    Secs    LocalTime   SOG
1  NZ1 01:09:2013 38150.0 10:35:49.997 22.17
2  NZ1 01:09:2013 38150.2 10:35:50.197 22.19
3  NZ1 01:09:2013 38150.4 10:35:50.397 22.02
4  NZ1 01:09:2013 38150.6 10:35:50.597 21.90
5  NZ1 01:09:2013 38150.8 10:35:50.797 21.84
6  NZ1 01:09:2013 38151.0 10:35:50.997 21.95

##### 3)
# A matrix showing the race times for each raceIDs
> raceTimes
    start      finish    
GER "11:10:02" "11:35:05"
SUI "11:10:02" "11:35:22"
NZ2 "11:10:02" "11:34:12"
US1 "11:10:01" "11:33:29"
US2 "11:10:01" "11:36:05"
POR "11:10:02" "11:34:31"
FRA "11:10:02" "11:34:45"
AUS "11:10:03" "11:36:48"
NZ1 "11:10:01" "11:35:16"
SWE "11:10:03" "11:35:08"
```

What I need to do is I need to calculate the average speed (SOG) of a boat "while it was racing" (between start and finish times).

So basically, I need to make a function similar to this:

```
> meanRaceSpeed("NZ1", boatList, raceTimes)
[1] 18.32  

> meanRaceSpeed("US1", boatList, raceTimes)
[1] 17.23
```

This is the one of the last question for my homework and I'm just completely stuck at all :(

I don't really even know where to start.

Could anyone please be able to give me some advice or support please?

Comment: Homework, hence hints only: you can use that "NZ1" argument to extract the subset of your matrix:  `newmat <- boatlist[boatlist[1]=="NZ1",]` and go on to work with the times columns in `newmat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need three arguments, because your three arguments are interrelated, i.e. when a boat is specified, its position in the `boatList` can, also, be specified and its `raceTimes` can be specified, too.

I didn't test the following function, because it was a bit painful to simulate random data, but I believe it might help:

```
meanRaceSpeed <- function(x)  #`x` is the boat's name
 {
  start_time <- raceTimes$start[rownames(raceTimes) == x] 
  finish_time <- raceTimes$finish[rownames(raceTimes) == x]

  #which `LocalTime` is the first with `start_time`
  start_LocalTime <- min(grep(start_time, boatList[[x]]$LocalTime))
  #which `LocalTime` is the last with `finish _time`
  #(if you want the first `finish_time` change `max` with `min`)
  finish_LocalTime <- max(grep(finish_time, boatList[[x]]$LocalTime))

  #which `SOG`s contain all the `LocalTimes` between start and finish
  #take their `mean`
  mean(boatList[[x]]$SOG[start_LocalTime : finish_LocalTime])
 }

#for all boats, something like:
sapply(raceIDs, meanRaceSpeed)
```

Sorry, if I misunderstood your question, though.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a homework assignment question, it's probably not going to serve anyone well to answer it directly.

For more about functions, see e.g. [Quick-R / User-defined functions](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html).

An example of a function with three parameters with which the function does nothing but returns them concatenated:

```
myfunc <- function(first, second, third) {
return(cat(first, second, third))
}
```

You can call that as `myfunc("foo","bar","baz")` and get as a result "foo bar baz".